# PySpark - Get top 5 most frequent values for every column (without UDF)

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Currently I'm gathering the top 5 most frequent values with a UDF.

The goal is to achieve the same result `without using UDF` and have the most efficient solution (avoid groupBy in loops).

Here's the code I'm using to have the result :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.select('A', 'B', ...)

@F.udf
def get_top_5_udf(x)
    from collections import Counter
    return [elem[0] for elem in Counter(x).most_common(5)]

agg_expr = [get_top_5_udf(F.collect_list(col)).alias(col) for col in df.columns]

df_top5 = df.agg(*agg_expr)
```

The result looks like the following :

```
# result
#+-----------------+--------------+---------------+
#|         A       |       B      |      ...      |
#+-----------------+--------------+---------------+
#| [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] |     [...]    |      ...      |
#+-----------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using count over window partitioned by each column before aggregating:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

result = df.select(*[
    F.struct(
        F.count(c).over(Window.partitionBy(c)).alias("cnt"),
        F.col(c).alias("val")
    ).alias(c) for c in df.columns
]).agg(*[
    F.slice(
        F.expr(f"transform(sort_array(collect_set({c}), false), x -> x.val)"),
        1, 5
    ).alias(c) for c in df.columns
])

result.show()
```

Comment: Now how do you do this within a GroupBy?